# Integrating bitcoin with php to accept donations

Tags: bitcoind, php

i have a blog and now i want to integrate bitcoin using php so that i'm able to accept donations or charity.

But i don't want any 3rd party processing like for creating qr code or invoices or content like that.
Is this possible or if not can someone point me in the direction of a proper integration method even if its 3rd party.

Comment: Maybe all you need to do is to display a receive address and the optionally QR code. The beauty of bitcoin.

Answer (score 2):

```
https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/PHP_developer_intro
```

This site shows all you need to get going. You'll need to run a dedicated bitcoind wallet on a server, which can accept JSON-RPC to call the various functions of bitcoind, which will respond back with a JSON object.